# How to compare field with _id in elasticsearch script?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match_all":{

            }
         },
         "filter":[
            {
               "script":{
                  "source":"doc['id'].value == doc['_id'].value",
                  "lang":"painless"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "track_total_hits":true
}
```

So `doc['_id'].value` is the line that causing error. How should i compare field value with _id value?

In normal documents "_id" is `string` and "id" is `long`, but i broke a few and now in them both are `strings`, how could I find them?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your **id** field type is **keyword**, so; you can't call `doc['id'].value` without `.keyword`.

try this:

```
"script": {
    "script": {
        "source": "doc['id.keyword'].value == doc['_id'].value",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not keyword but i missed `"script":{"script": ...}`